# When using GraphQL and Relay and Fragment, how to see the data?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, relayjs, react-relay

I am onto Step 4 of the Relay Tutorial at: https://relay.dev/docs/tutorial/fragments-1/

It was strange because when I don't use Fragment, and have the following code:

```
const NewsfeedQuery = graphql`
  query NewsfeedQuery {
    topStory {
      ...StoryFragment
    }
  }
`;

export default function Newsfeed() {

  const data = useLazyLoadQuery<NewsfeedQueryType>(
    NewsfeedQuery,
    {}
  )

  console.log("HERE 1", JSON.stringify(data, null, 4));
```

I was able to see in the dev console for the data:

```
HERE 1 {
    "topStory": {
        "title": "Local Yak Named Yak of the Year",
        "summary": "The annual Yak of the Year awards ceremony took place last night, and this year's winner is none other than Max, a beloved yak from the small town of Millville. Max, who is known for his friendly personality and hardworking nature, ...
  ...
```

However, once I started using Fragment and `useFragment`, the same console.log of `data` does not have any content of:

> The annual Yak of the Year awards ceremony took place last night

I wonder why the summary disappeared, yet it was able to work the same as before and have it shown on the webpage.  I know fragment data is "hidden" or "masked" by Relay, but even if it is hidden, it should still be inside of `data`, shouldn't it?  By what way can I see it using a `console.log()`?  (I mean right at this point, not at the point of `useFragment()`.

One possible way I am thinking is, could Relay be hiding all the fragment data by way of a function (or functions) inside of data and it does the returning the data? This way, `console.log()` won't be able to print it out.

At Story.jsx, there is:

```
  const data = useFragment(
    StoryFragment,
    story
  )
```

Overhere I can print out data, but I am just wondering right after the network fetch, how do I print out the data to see that what I needed is right there.

Comment: Please also add the code where you spread the fragment and where you use `useFragment`

Comment: added. At the `useFragment()` I can easily print out the data, or I can view it in the network tab in dev console, but what I am trying to find out is how to print it out right after `useLazyLoadQuery()`

Answer (score 0):

When using any query hook like `useLazyLoadQuery` with spread fragments Relay returns an object with some hidden fields, which tell Relay how to resolve those fragments when `useFragment` is called. Here is a quote from their documentation (https://relay.dev/docs/tutorial/fragments-1/#step-3--call-usefragment):

> Technically, `queryResult.topStory` [result object] is an object that contains some
> hidden fields that tell Relay's `useFragment` where to look for the data
> it needs. The fragment key specifies both which node to read from
> (here there's just one story, but soon we'll have multiple stories),
> and what fields can be read out (the fields selected by that specific
> fragment). The `useFragment` hook then reads that specific information
> out of Relay's local data store.

So to answer your original question:

> ...but I am just wondering right after the network fetch, how do I
> print out the data to see that what I needed is right there.

I don't think you easily can without using `useFragment`, using `@inline` on the fragment or not spreading there at all.